# I am unable to increase the size of the plot(graph)

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

I'm using matplotlib in spyder. Size of plot is not good enough. I can only see it in the console on the bottom right. Is there any way to make it large?

Comment: How do you create the figure? If you save it, is it still small? This will tell us if its a problem in your code or an issue with Spyder...

Comment: @BenT When I save it, the quality drops when I try to zoom it. But Do I have to save it every time? Is there a way to enlarge it within spyder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spyder images are supposed to be adjustable based on your setup. You can do this manually through the gui. I am guessing that you are not setting your figure size which is one way to increase the size of your figure.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16)) #Larger the numbers, the larger the figure
```

Another thing to consider when saving your figure. Use a vectorized format like a `pdf` and set your `dpi` so that you can zoom without degrading quality. This will make the file larger of course but it helps make publication quality figures.